# Database doesn't exist when php artisan migrate

Tags: php, sqlite, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I migrated my local laravel 5 project onto my AWS ec2 lamp Ubuntu server.
http://realtoraxe.com/realtoraxe/public/ but it shows

```
InvalidArgumentException in SQLiteConnector.php line 34: Database does not exist.
```

I changed the database.php set for sqlite

```
 <?php
 return array(
    'default' => 'sqlite',
    'connections' => array(
    'sqlite' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' =>    'http://realtoraxe.com/realtoraxe/storage/database.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
       ),
     ),
    );
   ?>
```

and I changed the .env to

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=mystring
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

it still doesn't see the database

Comment: did you install sqlite on your server? $ sudo apt-get install -y php5-sqlite and then $ sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: yes. its definitely my database.php file or .env file thats wrong. I reedited to show what i wrote. Do you know what i should write to point to http://realtoraxe.com/realtoraxe/storage/database.sqlite? Or a tutorail. I have googling but can't find it for sqlite.

Comment: Check this out https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel probably does not support much of the helper functions( e.g. `storage_path`) inside config files, but it surely does supports `env` function. [More info here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671#issuecomment-76634212)

That's the reason it's unable to locate your database. You should define the database in .env file or use the full path in the config file instead.

Comment: Hey, I changed both the database.php and .env file as you suggested (I edited my main post to show you). It still doesn't see it. Do you know what to write or know some tutorial. I can't see to find anything by googleing.

Comment: You are using  the web path, try using the physical path like `<full-path-to-laravel-directory>\storage\database.sqlite`